# facebook like box not working for FB Group

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I'm trying to use the facebooke like-box for a FB Group I'm creating a website for. I'm getting the error below. Where is the mistake coming from ? Thanks

```
https://www.facebook.com/groups/tapmichiana/

Could not retrieve the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Facebook encourages all it’s users to use “safe browsing” and therefor HTTPS when accessing the platform … the like button itself seems to be a little behind on that issue.

Try pointing your like button to `http://www.facebook.com/groups/tapmichiana/` instead, the non-SSL version of your group’s page on Facebook – then it should work.